# spread an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, spread-syntax

in storybook I have an object inside an object for the default props of the component

```
const TemplatePicker = () => {
 const data = {
  data: {
   foo: 'bar' 
 }
}
 return <Picker data={data} />
}
export const Basic = TemplatePicker.bind({});
Basic.args = {
 ...Basic.args,
 data: {
  ...Basic.args.data,
  foo: null
 }
}
```

but I get an error (storybook doesn't render but there is no error in console or in the terminal)
is this valid syntax? and if not is there another way?

Comment: The syntax is correct, but perhaps the logic isn't. What are you trying to do? What is `Basic.args` supposed to be? It might be undefined or not an object, but you said you don't get any errors. Is `Picker` a component you wrote or is it from a library?

Comment: A component I wrote, just render an elemnt according to the value. Can be null instead if its clearer